# TrueTone flickering when switching user accounts (display color changes briefly)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, system-settings, preferences

When I switch between logged in user accounts, I noticed TrueTone flickers (the display color shifts to TrueTone briefly). It turns on when switching to the next account for a few seconds, and then turns back off. All the accounts I am using have the TrueTone setting disabled. Most or all times, the TrueTone comes on at the login window even before switching into the next account.

My attempts to fix (no luck):

- Make sure TrueTone is on for all accounts
- Reinstall MacOS

So I am wondering:

1. Is this a "normal" thing that others are experiencing?
2. Is there any
   way to fix it so that it doesn't happen?

I am on a 2019 16 inch Macbook Pro with Intel UHD Graphics 630.

*Let me know if any other info would be useful. Thanks for your time!*

Comment: I'd be more inclined to thinking it's the display profile that unloads, then reloads the other account's profile [this probably happens even if it's the same profile]. I see the same on Macs that don't have TrueTone or any other colour/brightness control.

Answer (score 1):

You would need Apple to change their implementation to address this IMO.

I think this is normal and I can reproduce it easily from your description. My understanding is the user preferences get rolled back on log out and enabled / processed on log in which causes the shift. The same shift happens at boot as well when the GPU isn’t managing color at all and the system settings engage.

Comment: That's what makes me think it's the display profile, not TrueTone - you see the same thing as the Mac is booting - easier to see on older Macs with a light grey background at boot, but I see it on my MBP too..

Comment: Yes - I believe the order is GPU engaged with full drivers, display default curves applied, system defined curves applied (if there even are system level settings), user defined curves applied, then finally True Tone and Night Shift applied in an order I can’t discern. Quite a lot happening under the hood @Tetsujin